# How to Format Jupyter notebook in VSCode？

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

We can format python code in the jupyter notebook in the browser. After I change to VSCode and use the Microsoft extension, I find I can not format Jupyter notebook any more. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "formatting code". You edit code as usual: Enter to start a new line, Tab to indent. What is missing?

Answer (score 39):

As Kyle Carow stated in their answer to Ian Huff: Formatting of notebooks is available by now.

- MacOS: `Option+Shift+F`
- Windows: `Alt+Shift+F`

Pressing these keys will either trigger a formatting of the active cell or the notebook as a whole if no cell is active.

Comment: A blank line gets added to the end of every code cell that Black formats.

Comment: It should be the same key combination as formatting document, kept trying it and had to look it up...

Answer (score 18):

Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Is what worked for me with Black formatter set up on VS Code Version: 1.64.2

Or right click "Format Notebook" to format entire notebook.

[Format Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKVWx.png)

Comment: While Shift + Alt + F works, I am unable to find anything like "Format Notebook"...do I need a different Jupyter extension, or is this not in the latest vscode?

Answer (score 10):

I do not think VS Code support formatting of code cells, but if you use the `black` code formatter, then you can use the blackcellmagic `%%black` to format the code in a cell.

You need to have pip install `black` and `blackcellmagic`, details here: https://github.com/csurfer/blackcellmagic

Answer (score 7):

If you have a Jupyter notebook open in VS Code with the Jupyter notebook extension, it should be possible to format code cells with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>I</kbd>.

I'm not sure if this shortcut differs between operating systems, you can check what the shortcut is yourself by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> and then searching for "Format cell". The shortcut should be displayed then.

Comment: This is what worked for me in Ubuntu based Linux distro

Answer (score 5):

I'm not exactly sure what is being asked here. But currently in VS Code the notebook editor and interactive window do not support formatting python code.

However we are moving to a new UI for those features which will support all the formatting features of VS Code in .py files. If you try out VS Code - Insiders now you should see this support and can try it out. This new UI will eventually be rolling out to VS Code stable.

Edit: The new UI which supports formatting in cells is now out by default for stable users.

Comment: From my perspective (s)he's asking for code prettifier / autoformatter. That should be available for .py files within vscode, right? But not for .ipynb notebooks within vscode.

Comment: Yes that's how I understand the question. And as of now there is actually formatting support for ipynb, but it's only available in VS Code - Insiders. Support will be rolling out into stable VS Code in the next months.

Comment: @IanHuff do you have a link to a page where we can follow status on this?
For jupyterlab, there is a great extension called jupyterlab-code-formatter that makes this super easy

Comment: The new UI should be out now for stable users.

Comment: FYI: you can now run your code autoformatter in notebook cells by using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+I. Black seems to add an extra line at the bottom of the cell though, which is annoying.

Answer (score 5):

You can set VS code to automatically format your Jupyter Notebook file every time you save the file. To do so:

1. go to settings... > settings (on mac cmd + +)
2. Search for "format notebook"
3. Check the box that say "Format a notebook on save. ..."

Answer (score 1):

In the Vscode setting (UI) (ctr+shift+p),
after setting up Black formatter and Jupyter notebook formatting,
VScode will auto format Jupyter notebook when saving the notebook.

[image: Black formatter]

[image: Jupyter notebook formatting]

[image: auto format Jupyter notebook when saving the notebook].

Vscode version: 1.81.1

Answer (score 0):

After I check the document of autppep8 in vscode extension shop, I find that I need delete "python.formatting.provider": "none" in "my setting.json". And I can format cell and py file with the option in right click.