# Format a Jupyter notebook on save in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, formatting

I use `black` to automatically format all of my Python code whenever I save in VSCode. I'd like the same functionality, but within a Jupyter notebook in VSCode.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747615/how-to-format-jupyter-notebook-in-vscode) shows how to right click and format a cell or a whole notebook from the right click context menu, or a keyboard shortcut. Can I make this happen on save instead?

It looks like there is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120432) related to this, but it is over a year old.

Are there any good workarounds? Maybe a way to set the format notebook option to the same keybinding as save?

UPDATE:

If you like me want this functionality to be added please go to the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7058) and upvote it, the devs said they will need a bunch of upvotes before it's considered.

UPDATE:

This got enough attention that it has been added!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good news! This is now an option in the newest VSCode release (1.77)

Setting `"notebook.formatOnSave.enabled": true` will do the trick

You can read more about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_77#_format-on-save).

If you have `black` already enabled for Python it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is not officially supported, but there could be workarounds.

From janosh's [reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120432#issuecomment-1133959273) on GitHub:

There is a setting `editor.codeActionsOnSave` but it doesn't allow running arbitrary shell commands (for security reasons?) so you'd need to install an extension like [Run On Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) and get it to call `black path/to/file.ipynb` on save events.

Sadly even that doesn't work right now since VS Code does not yet expose lifecycle events for notebooks. The issue to upvote for that is: [Improve workspace API for Notebook lifecycle to support (at least) saving events](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130799)

If both get implemented, you should be able to add this to your settings to auto-format Jupyter notebooks:

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
  "commands": [
    {
      "match": "\\.ipynb$",
      "cmd": "black ${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have installed support for JNs: `pip install 'black[jupyter]'`

Answer (score 1):

There are no plans yet according to [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7058).

Answer (score 1):

A simple enough solution is to set the format notebook option to the same keybinding as save, as you suggested. Here's how you can do that with VSCode Tasks:

`tasks.json` (in Command Palette "Tasks: Open User Tasks"):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmd:save",
            "command": "${command:workbench.action.files.save}"
        },
        {
            "label": "cmd:format-notebook",
            "command": "${command:notebook.format}"
        },
        {
            "label": "cmd:format-notebook+save",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "cmd:format-notebook",
                "cmd:save"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`keybindings.json` (in Command Palette "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"):

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "cmd:format-notebook+save"
    }
]
```

Comment: On mac, use `"key": "cmd+s"`

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your `keybindings.json`  it should also run both `format cell` and `save file` on your jupyter notebook, when typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+s",
        "command": "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": ["notebook.formatCell","workbench.action.files.save",]
        },
        "when": "editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && inCompositeEditor && notebookEditable && !editorReadonly && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.notebook'"
    },
```

Conversely if you want to save the whole notebook on save, you can replace `notebook.formatCell` by `notebook.format`.