# black formatter won't be called when editing notebooks in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-black

I am trying to enforce formatting on *.ipynb* files from VSCode.
My settings.json looks like this:

```
{
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "python.formatting.provider": "black",
   "python.formatting.blackPath": "C:\\Python\\3.6.8\\Scripts\\black.exe",
}
```

VSCode's Python extension is installed as well as black and black[jupyter] (path above is correct).
This works fine for regular *.py* files but not for *.ipynb* (nothing happen upon save).

I've tried to associate *.ipynb* files to Python, it didn't work either:

```
  "files.associations": {
     "*.ipynb": "python"
  }
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103359/format-a-jupyter-notebook-on-save-in-vscode

Answer (score 0):

Since March 2023 / 1.77 there's built-in support for [format on save for Jupyter Notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_77#_format-on-save).

In May 2013 / 1.79 Visual Studio Code gained the option [format on cell execution](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_format-on-run):

```json
"notebook.formatOnCellExecution": true
```